# Charles video playing unavailable

Tags: http-proxy, charles-proxy

I'm testing an Andoird & IOS app which includes a feature that allows to watch videos.
The problem is - when I use Charles, with a proxy server and a hotspot with my laptop, the videos won't play.

Of course that the videos are playing when I'm not using Charles.

My suggestion is that Charles has some kind of a port limitation, and that's why I can't get the content of the video.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try wireshark/fiddler. It might be because your app uses https and it doesn't trust your Charles certificate chain. The certificate could be pinned.

Comment: I tried, but the traffic is in SSL. How can I be able to see the traffic not encrypted?

Comment: Eve. You should ask the NSA. :P

Answer (score 0):

Since it is SSL traffic, you should not be allowed to sniff the traffic. The is the POINT of SSL.

To get around this, you need to break SSL on your phone. To do this you have to tell your phone to implicitly trust EVERYTHING that your PC is sending you. To do this you have to install your Charles SSL certificate as a root CA certificate.

**THIS IS HIGHLY DANGEROUS AND ONCE YOU HAVE DONE THIS YOU SHOULD NOT TRUST YOUR BROWSER TO PROTECT YOU FROM HACKERS STEALING YOUR ONLINE BANKING DETAILS UNTIL YOU REMOVE YOUR THE CERTIFICATE.**

Here is a tutorial on how to do this on an android phone :)

http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2014/install-charlesproxy-ca-certificate-on-android

Comment: I know that SSL is unbreakable, and it's not my question. I have succeeded in watching the traffic, but the problem is with videos which aren't playing for some reason.

Comment: Perhaps the client has certificate pinning.